# Python 3.7 Error: AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'run'

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.7

I am running following code in pycharm with python 3.7. but getting this error.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('dir', shell=True)
```

Error Message: AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'run'

Comment: can you provide the error message?

Comment: AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'run'

Comment: Don't name your `py` file same with a module.

Comment: try `print(subprocess.__file__)`. Did you get a subprocess.py in the a python system folder? (likely the same folder as `os.__file__`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the filename of your program subprocess.py also?  If so, change that and run again to confirm